# Extract array from JSON object containing multiple types

Tags: c#, arrays, json

(Just a heads up, I'm very new to C#)

(See sample code and JSON structure below)

I can't figure out how to pull "data" out of the JSON reponse and put it into a data table. The variable "response" is just raw JSON data. So far I've figured out how to parse the JSON into a JObject...so now it has two members (data, meta). Now I'm trying to figure out how to get joTest["data"] into a DataTable. The handful of attempts I've made, keep giving me an error when it sees the "meta" member. Maybe I shouldn't be using a Data Table?

Also, in case it changes anything, I don't need the "links" from the "data" members.

I've tried searching for "Converting JObject into Data Table" But I'm not finding a lot of useful results.

```
public void PerformFeed()
{
    string response;
    response = Blah.SendMessage().Result;

    JObject joTest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(response);
}
```

Json Data Structure

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "Val1": "1234",
            "Val2": "foo1",
            "Val3": "bar1",
            "links": [
                {
                    "rel": "self",
                    "uri": "/blah/1234"
                },
                {
                    "rel": "pricing_data",
                    "uri": "/blah/1234/pricing_data"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Val1": "5678",
            "Val2": "foo2",
            "Val3": "bar2",
            "links": [
                {
                    "rel": "self",
                    "uri": "/blah/5678"
                },
                {
                    "rel": "pricing_data",
                    "uri": "/blah/5678/pricing_data"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "pagination": {
            "total": 2,
            "count": 2,
            "per_page": 25,
            "current_page": 1,
            "total_pages": 1,
            "links": []
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I've figured out a "solution" but I really don't think it's a good solution. I built a datatable and then used a foreach statement on the JObject to populate the data table that way. It seems very inefficient...but for now it works. Hopefully I'll find a better way.

```
public void PerformFeed()
{
    DataTable Items = new DataTable();
    Items.Columns.Add("Val1");
    Items.Columns.Add("Val2");
    Items.Columns.Add("Val3");

    string response = Blah.SendMessage().Result;
    JObject Data = JObject.Parse(response);

    foreach (JObject jo in Data["data"])
    {
        Items.Rows.Add(jo["Val1"], jo["Val2"], jo["Val3"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: “The handful of attempts...”, show your best attempt and the error it gives.

Comment: @blins my most recent attempt is the same code above, but swap in the line "DataSet dtTest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(response);". When running that I get an error, which says "Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable. Expected StartArray, got StartObject. Path 'meta'". I understand why I get this error...But I don't know how to get around it. I was trying to follow this article: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDataSet.htm

Comment: i would deserialize into `dynamic` - works v nicely

Answer (score 1):

There is this really nice [online utility](https://jsonutils.com/) that helps extracting C# classes from JSON objects. I think the problem here is with your JSON, you're missing a comma ",". You would easily be able to spot the error with some [online JSON formatter / validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/). Rest the deserialization is pretty straightforward. Try the following:

```
JObject obtainedObject = JObject.Parse(JsonString);
```

Following would be the structure of your obtained object:

```
public class RequiredClass
{
    public IList<Datum> data { get; set; }
    public Meta meta { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public string Val1 { get; set; }
    public string Val2 { get; set; }
    public string Val3 { get; set; }
    public IList<Link> links { get; set; }
}

public class Link
{
    public string rel { get; set; }
    public string uri { get; set; }
}

public class Pagination
{
    public int total { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
    public int per_page { get; set; }
    public int current_page { get; set; }
    public int total_pages { get; set; }
    public IList<object> links { get; set; }
}

public class Meta
{
    public Pagination pagination { get; set; }
}
```

Update:

Here's is how you extract your *array* and convert that to a *DataTable*:

```
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
JToken dataArray = jObject["data"];
DataTable dt = (DataTable) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(dataArray.ToString(), (typeof(DataTable)));
```

To avoid the surplus casting, you can try the following using the class structure already mentioned above:

```
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
JToken dataArray = jObject["data"];
List<Datum> requiredList = new List<Datum>();

foreach (var item in dataArray)
{
    Datum obj = new Datum();
    obj.Val1 = (string) item["Val1"] ?? "";
    obj.Val2 = (string) item["Val2"] ?? "";
    obj.Val3 = (string) item["Val3"] ?? "";
    obj.links = new List<Link>();

    foreach(var subItem in item["links"])
    {
        Link lnk = new Link();
        lnk.rel = (string) subItem["rel"] ?? "";
        lnk.uri = (string) subItem["uri"] ?? "";
        obj.links.Add(lnk);
    }

    requiredList.Add(obj);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the typo. That was my bad. I manually modified the data in the JSON before posting it since the API I'm using is returning info I'm not allowed to make that information public.

Comment: The issue is trying to get the "data" member into a datatable, so that I can append additional "columns"/information for each list item using a different api.

Comment: Also, thank you for the links, those will be very helpful in the future.

Comment: @chadwin I see, please check the updated answer. Let me know if it solves the issue.

Comment: Ahhhh, very interesting....so you're parsing the whole thing into a jObject, then extracting the "data" member, then turning it back into a string, and sort of re-parsing it again into a data table.

Comment: @chadwin Please re-check, I have updated the solution with another alternative.

Comment: Looks similar to my "solution" I wrote up earlier today. I just updated my post with it. I'm reading the JSON data into a datatable. Is there a benefit to using Datum/Link vs using a DataTable?